# OpenGL - Get amount of texel accesses in a rendering call

Tags: opengl, glsl, profiling, textures, texel

Is there any way in OpenGL to get the amount of texel accesses (invocations of the texture() method) being performed in one rendering call?

For example, using glBeginQuery with *GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED* or *FRAGMENT_SHADER_INVOCATIONS_ARB* gets the primitives generated or the fragment shader invocations on the rendering call, respectively. Is there any way to do the same with texture accesses?

Comment: Instrument each `texture()` call with an atomic increment?

Comment: I thought about that option but I'm kind of worried about the performance hit that can be produced by accessing concurrently so many times the same variable by all the fragment invocations... and having to find each texture() call to paste the atomic adding after it will be pretty time consuming (although I maybe could do it when parsing the shaders). But yeah, maybe that's the only available option, and it certainly will work. Thank you!